# Dupe Hammer too powerful?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I see this quite often - people who have a gold badge on a tag may know a lot about the tag, but they still fall victim like any other person to thinking they can mind-read other people and close questions as a dupe purely on some unverified assumption about what the poster intended.

Another problem is that the re-open queue doesn't seem to work well. I hardly ever see a question being re-opened even after all the problems indicated in the close reason have been resolved. Or, as in this case, when one dupe hammer user voted to close as a duplicate that is clearly incorrect.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418638/java-how-to-close-program-on-input

In this question, the duper-hammerer just assumed that the question had something to do with closing the console that started the program, even though this is not mentioned anywhere in the question. The actual problem of the OP is pretty simply visible in the source code, and has no relation at all with the supposed duplicate.

Yet after 15 hours, only 3 reopen votes have been cast. I doubt that the necessary quorum of re-open votes will ever be reached. **Update:** the question has been reopened and closed as no-repro.

Why not change this dupe hammer to require *at least* two different persons to close for the same duplicate? That's still better than the required number of votes from non-golden-badges.

Comment: *I doubt that the necessary quorum of re-open votes will ever be reached.* Why? The Reopen Votes queue should be able to handle this.

Comment: I don't get the problem.  If you *know* how to ask the question so it doesn't require mind-reading or can avoid fanciful interpretation then just ask it.  You can answer it as well.  We don't give a hoot about who asked it, who answered it or who close-voted it.  Just the Q+A matters.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not my question. I know how to answer it, but I can't, because it was shot down but an overactive dupe hammer minutes after it was asked

Comment: As I said, go answer it.  You are clearly very qualified to ask the proper question to go along with it.

Comment: So, I disagree with the premise that the dupe hammer is too powerful, but I do agree with the premise that this particular question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: The gold hammer also comes with reopen powers. If the question scope has been reasonably clarified (not just minor bytext added), it's perfectly fine to ping the closevoter to quicken that process. If the goal is just to close it more correctly as off-topic / not reprodicible, that's somewhat pointless IMO. (It may just attract misleading/vague answers meanwhile; proper closing takes even longer.)

Answer (score 30):

I am the person who closed the question. There are some factors you are not considering:

- While you were outraged that the question was closed, the person who asked the question *never came back*, despite the fact that you and I were commenting on their question. Maybe it did help them, **you don't even know that it didn't**.
- If you run the program, **as written**, the program **terminates** immediately when you type `2` in the console. Therefore, there are only three possibilities:

  1. There is no question to be asked here. The program works perfectly, and therefore the problem is a **simple error that is not reproducible**.
  2. The person has a different issue, that being **the one in the linked duplicate** (console window not closing after a Java application terminates).
  3. The user did not adequately explain what problem they were having; in other words, it was **unclear what they were asking**.
- In any of these cases, this question should remain closed. Perhaps it should be closed as no-repro or unclear instead of as duplicate. In this case, I chose to give the asker *the benefit of the doubt* that they had an actual question, rather than assuming they had posted working code and then asking us to debug a problem that *did not exist*.

The reason that gold badge powers exist is that those of us who have them are trusted that we know the language well enough to [know how to use them judiciously:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/200235)

> We're doing this for duplicates only to start, because it's incredibly silly *not* to do this. *Not* giving people with gold tag badges more abilities in their tags is just wasting some very valuable signal - here's why:
>
> - If you have a gold badge in your tag, you *know* what's been asked before, in several iterations, and where to find it.
> - If you have a gold badge in your tag, you *usually* have a great deal of knowledge about the topic and can consider technical accuracy along with perceived quality

There are many people who have a Java gold badge. I have  been overridden before and I have overridden other gold badge holders before. The good thing about this is that we have a reopen queue. [Three other users agreed with me that this should remain closed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9408528). I see stuff in the reopen queue get four quick reopen votes *all the time*; the reopen queue is almost always at zero, unlike close votes, these requests do get processed.

All that being said, if the original asker had come back to explain why that duplicate didn't help them, I would have probably reopened it and probably edited it as well.

Comment: 16 hours isn't a lot of time, y'know.  Who knows, they may have been getting things ready for the Labor Day weekend.

Comment: As another gold badge holder (though in a different tag), I completely agree with your rationale. If the question needs to be closed because it's not clear what the question actually is, but you can (by virtue of the expertise that got you the badge in the first place) identify the most likely option, then you should absolutely use the dupehammer. Not only does this stand a good chance to get the asker their answer faster than the close as unclear->edit->reopen cycle, but _it's easier for the question to be reopened if you're wrong_ (because you or another gold badger can do it unilaterally).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I agree, and I want to emphasize that I absolutely would have reopened it myself if there had been a good edit by OP and a ping comment.

Answer (score 11):

No, the dupe-hammer isn't too powerful. It is a great way for those few members with a gold-badge in their most comfortable tag that want to moderate posts to be effective.

Most of them are very conscious about their new powers and use them in good faith. If you want to prove abuse the question you choose as an example is not the best one. It looks to me like a simple mistake that probably is not much helpful for future visitors. One of the many other questions about `System.exit` can be used as a dupe. In that light the chosen dupe maybe not the best one but it will do for me.

With regard to the reopen-queue not working: You can always hop in the SO Close voters room if you really feel a post needs [a second chance](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9408528) after it has been fixed. Be aware that a some of those gold-dupe-hammer users are a regular in that room so you'll need to bring some good arguments to the table.

The dupe-hammer is restricted in its use. There are enough safe guards if members abuse their powers, like meta, flags, chat rooms, comments. I don't think, given the current evidence, a change in the policy is needed.

Comment: I never said that it was malicious, but it certainly wasn't very nice for a new user to have their question closed with a completely irrelevant duplicate. Everyone can make mistakes, and that's why we shouldn't have one person being able to close questions. I certainly don't want to have that power; I don't know how this dupe hammer works once you get the power, but I hope you can choose not to exercise it - else I will not be nominating duplicates anymore.

Comment: Fair enough, edited one word out. You noticed the dupe-hammer and came to meta to raise an issue. That is how all moderation works here, if I edit something incorrect it gets rolled back, if I close vote something incorrect it gets re-opened, if I flag NAA it gets declined. The perceived power is very relative and minimal IMHO. But you can't switch it off but I have seen one FR for that, if not here then on MSE. @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: Would you have preferred the question be closed as "unclear what you're asking", with no answer at all, @ErwinBolwidt? Because that's the other option here.

Answer (score -5):

## This isn't a duplicate question *at all*.

### This feels like an abuse of the gold tag privilege.

So, full disclosure:  I too have a gold badge in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), and I use it *very often*.  However, I disagree with its closure *as a duplicate* for two the reasons stated in [durron597's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305433/1079354):

> - There is no question to be asked here. The program works perfectly, and therefore the problem is a **simple error that is not
>     reproducible.**
> - The user did not adequately explain what problem they were having; in other words, it was **unclear what they were asking.**

I ran the code too and I didn't see any issues with the code that they were encountering.  So, I don't think that this issue was reproducible.  **It should be closed as that.**

Closing something as a duplicate implies that the question is very nearly the same as to what is being asked on some other question, and that the solution exists on that answer.  In other words, if I were to answer the question, I too would arrive at the same conclusion as another answer.  Here, I don't arrive at that conclusion; I arrive at, "This is working as they describe that they want it to work, so why would there be a duplicate for it?"

I'm not a fan of this sort of usage of the dupe hammer *at all*.  If you're going to close it, then close it with a decent message; otherwise, it's just an abuse of power.  You should give OP a *good* sign post to go off of as opposed to any old sign post.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, I gave the OP the *benefit of the doubt* that the duplicate question was the one they were asking.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that.  Even though the dupe is *sort of* related, it's just not a duplicate question at all, as there's no actual problem with the code as authored.  You demonstrate as much in your answer.

Comment: He wants to `exit the window is the user inputs "2",`; the program already does terminate. Therefore, I assumed that he *wanted to close the window*, which is *exactly* what the duplicate is discussing.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing that the duplicate does address that, but the question as authored does *exactly* what the OP wants it to do.  There's no question to be asked here; that is, the duplicate question/answer does not help them understand their problem.  If they can come up with a scenario in which they *can* reproduce an issue with it not closing on `"2"`, then they can edit it and get it reopened.  Until then, I strongly feel that it isn't a duplicate, but it's not reproducible.

Comment: Well, I don't agree, but I consider my comment pointing him to the duplicate plus closing as no-repro as an acceptable compromise. I agree to disagree.