# Troubleshooting question wrongly closed as duplicate of "how to debug" reference post

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, dupehammer

See this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32925609/1407478). A user have single handed without further notice closed the question with reference to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/1407478).

But I fail to see how OP should get his question answered by that reference. OP has at least two issues, none of them are targeted in the "duplicated answer".

I would expect "This question already has an answer here" actually pointed to an answer. The suggested reference contains generic answers to common PHP errors and warnings - but that is not what OP is asking for, and that is not his problem.

What to do? Simply reopen and answer?

The Point is : **It is not a duplicate**!

Comment: Without judging or inspecting from the links you gave (PHP questions leave me shuddering for hours), if you really think it's worth it, vote to reopen and leave a comment why maybe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for downvoting this question. Why?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - That depends on the definition of "worth it".  I definitely think this is a wrong close.  OP does not get his problem solved. On the other hand, the question is not very generic, it is isolated to OP's code alone - not many people, if any, will benefit from an answer in the future - but is SO about helping people or what?

Comment: _"... it is isolated to OP's code alone ..."_ That's probably whole of the key in your question. If the Q is more like asking for a too special personal problem, it's not likely to be helpful for future research. So I'd rather not vote to reopen. (I didn't dv BTW).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, That does not make the suggested answer to a duplicate.

Comment: Only questions are marked as duplicates, that doesn't make existing answers invalid or such.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, do you say that "_This question already has an answer here_" is a trashcan that can be used for all sorts of reasons to close a question? I would have believed - but now I can see I am wrong - that "_This question already has an answer here_" actually referred to a duplicated question and a good answer to that.

Comment: #soreadytohelp has now a completely new meaning to me.

Comment: Related: [Dupe hammer too powerful?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305429) [Is there a benefit to closing a question as a duplicate of more than one question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254710)

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ - "Only questions are marked as duplicates, that doesn't make existing answers invalid or such_"??? And this is a comment to ...? I am just asking how on earth to respond to an obviosly wrong reference to a duplicated question - nothing else.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - "_That's probably whole of the key in your question_", no, the whole key in my question is written in my question,. It is a false duplicate reference. But I can see now I just should have been indifferent, not taken notice. Just let people close for any obscure reason and move on, dont care at all.

Comment: @davidkonrad Well, there's probably nothing bad about an answer given for a duplicate, that solves the OPs main problem or misconception. I'm using my C++ dupe hammer just by judging the answers given for a specialised problem asked in the question. If the question is a good signpost for generalised problems research, it will be kept alive as other users find it helpful. Same regarding any answers applied with it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "_there's probably nothing bad about an answer given for a duplicate_" - I give up - you clearly not understand my point, and why do I even bother :(  I didnt even care for the question in the first place, I was just baffled over the wrong "duplicate" reference. Now OP will 1) ask a new question (that perhaps will be closed = more trash on SO servers)  or 2) give up on SO.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, thanks for that reference - can see I am not alone :) Normally I do not have any objections, but this time it was too obvious - simply a wrong close vote. But if this is broad acceptable, then I just may reconsider my view on SO and how people are managing their moderation powers. I thought meta could be used as an "stop, look and listen" - but if closing questions to references that is not duplicates is what you want, then this is what you get, of course.

Comment: @davidkonrad I still didn't inspect the links, that seems to be a question to be answered by the domain experts, I'm not one. Maybe make your question clearer, using X, Y, foo and bar to demonstrate the difference in question and marked duplicate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - "_I still didn't inspect the links_" that is why your comments are soooo OT.  My question is chrystal clear,  can wonder why you comment to a question you not even try to understand.

Comment: @davidkonrad Well, you should make your question self contained. I already told you, why I'm not following your links.

Comment: I am not a pedagogue and I certainly expect some selflearning-skills here on SO :)  Over and out. I do not care, really - and if everybody else dont care too - we are all happy.  Now I am just indifferent _and_ disappointed.

Comment: @davidkonrad _"over and out"_ doesn't fit that well asking for [tag:discussion] :-P ...

Comment: @davidkonrad OK, I've inspected it now, but the question as asked simply deserves to be closed and deleted, no matter for which particular reason. Dupe hammer voters just try to speed up that process sometimes. The correct close reason would have been that the question is too broad, or requires a [MCVE] to be on-topic. (still shuddering, and it's not going to end soon, as I've been afraid of).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to oppose questions marked as duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252691/how-to-oppose-questions-marked-as-duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This question may already have an answer here" - but it does not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not)

Comment: That question and answer don't cover _any_ of the salient points presented here, @PetahChristian, and it's also about a question that _hasn't been closed yet_, let alone by the dupehammer. It's posted by the person who asked the SO question, which is not the case here, and largely about the automatic banner that is only visible to the OP at the top of the dupe-proposed question. Pretty much _nothing_ there applies to the situation davidkonrad is asking about. psubsee's answer provides no useful advice for someone in davidkonrad's situation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow; it should be closed.

The OP has stated that e  has no knowledge about the code e's posted:

> Not sure if this script are good too, I take the example from Internet. I want just a simple secure login with sessions, logout and restrict access to some pages. Arrrgh!

This puts the question, as posted, into resource request territory. Given this lack of understanding and description of the problem, it also falls afoul of the MCVE reason, and [at least flirts with being "Too broad"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/159251).

Given all that, the close voter decided to use his dupehammer to a) close the question [as quickly as possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/159251) and b) point the asker at [a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851) that just might get em started on understanding [one of the major problems with the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305433/).

I find this [an entirely appropriate use of the dupehammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305433/), and I think you should too: the asker, as the question stands, is not really helpable within the Q&A format of Stack Overflow. Closure indicates that, but using duplicate closure provides what little help is available.

Unless you believe the question shouldn't be closed at all, I don't think there's anything you need to do here.

A final note: if you see someone constantly using the dupehammer to close questions with completely unrelated targets, that's certainly something that would warrant a moderator flag. If you see it happen one or two times, here or there, just comment and ask the closer to explain. I've made at least one mistake with my duplicate closure, and re-opened when it was pointed out to me.

Comment: The concept "dupehammer" is new to me. I am not following meta regularily.  I can understand why, I did that even before I asked here on meta - but still the reason for closing the question is **wrong**. It should - in my opinion - go through the "normal" close procedure "_why is this code not working_" or similar.  The result is 1) more trash (if the question just is repeated over and over, and I have seen that) 2) people give up on SO, because they see their honest questions being closed without any good reason besides a llame reference to a series of answers they cannot use.

Comment: I think it is **far** better to convince OP why the question should be closed, or why it is not suitable for the Q&A concept,  rather than it is more or less coincidentally closed just because someone with a "dupehammer" come by ...

Comment: Sorry about the terminology, @davidkonrad: [origin of the term](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/159251).

Comment: I understand what you're saying, @davidkonrad, but given the choice between simple closure and closure with a pointer to a probably-useful resource, I firmly believe the latter is a better outcome.

Comment: "_... I firmly believe the latter is a better outcome_ " - And **THAT** you could have told in a comment for more than an hour ago.  Besides learning the concept "dupehammer" I also learned that avatars here on meta are more eager to patronize and make fun out of people who are not spenting their whole lives on meta, rather than actually answer or comment a seriously meant question.  I am really disappointed.  Your answer is good, but the long row of stupid comments above was unnessecary. And yes, I look at you @πάνταῥεῖ :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I don't like your tone here, it outcomes slightly aggressive. What's bothering you so much in this _discussion_ (you already left over & out, didn't you)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell, "_if you see someone constantly using the dupehammer to close questions with completely unrelated targets_"  - that I have never seen.  It is the first time actually I had been baffled or disagreed (as mentioned elsewhere) - but I have seen the same poor question repeated over and over several times. I now understand, and agree - it was a great answer and explanation you came up with.

Comment: "The same poor question repeated over and over several times" was exactly the reason for the creation of this privilege of unilateral duplicate closure (and the reference question used as the target in this case), @davidkonrad. I'm glad you find my explanation useful.