# Understanding the community and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I'm not ranting; I am just somewhat confused about the community and the purpose of Stack Overflow.

I usually do my best not to [be a vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) and just leech code, so I go through questions on Stack Overflow and answer if I can when I can. Recently I have been asking a lot of "basic" questions on JavaScript and have been met with a lot of negativity, and been negative rep'd, etc.

One question even got marked as a duplicate within 60 seconds of posting...which leads to the basis of this question, to help me better understand.

I asked the user why he marked it as a duplicate, purely as I had already checked that particular question, and it did not resolve the issue. Another user pointed out I had a syntax error in which, **then** that question answered mine. However it led to a frustrated "rude" commenting conversation, both from myself (ashamedly) and him. He was stating that Stack Overflow is not a debugging service and clearly gave the impression he knew it was a syntax error, so I was asking why he did not mark it as off-topic as I would have **realised** I had an error in my code and resolved it.

However I'm not going to rant, and stick to where I am going with this.
Stack Overflow is not a **debugging** site. However, it **IS** a Q/A site. Now if I feel I need to ask a question, then I come to Stack Overflow, usually after hours of searching and checking. Yet this seems to be more and more frowned upon, especially within the JavaScript community. And I cannot understand why?

Some people have some really easy questions and some people have some really hard questions. The community is of mixed levels in mixed languages and we learn from each other by asking questions about our code.
So yes, some people do just want a debugging service, yet some ask questions in a manner in which they ask for help to explain how something works (various levels), and get ridiculed and negative rep'd for it.

So is Stack Overflow still a Q&A site for people? After all, it is about **helping** other people of all levels and continuing to do so, or is it just turning into an archived library, which it would not have been able to do without the Q&A in the first place?

Comment: _Usually after hours of searching and checking_ Did you make it obvious in your post? Did you explain why you wrote code the way you did? Why you thought it should work? Why you thought the error shouldn't have occurred? All that backed by references?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071151/cannot-read-property-style-of-null-javascript I believe i made it obvious i had been searching, and what i thought the problem may have been (this was due to the "duplicates" not working, but i didn't exactly "state" i had been searching, However it turned out it was a loading error initially, due to a syntax error, which stopped the "duplicate" from working, Perhaps if you think i did not "state" clearly enough i will be more detailed in future, However in which way is SO going now, Is it still Q/A or turning into a library?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a frustratingly rude community, or at least the rude people stick out more. And there's a contingent that _likes_ being rude, so it's hard to fix that.

Comment: A few points: 1) With "SO is not a debugging site" the user probably meant that SO is not here to do another users job and solve/debug their code. If you put effort into your question and debugged your code, but didn't get it fixed that is totally fine! 2) Especially with basic questions you want to make sure that for one you show some effort, e.g. what you have tried or what you have found by searching, and that if you found similar questions that you can include them in your question and show what you already found and tried out, so that others don't suggest the same as you already tried...

Comment: Also most of the times there are already many Q&A's for basic questions so you really want to makre sure you checked them and if they didn't helped you, you still show that you have found them. 3) If you ask a basic understanding question you also really want to make sure that you explain what you already understand and what part you don't understand. 4) Last point, if you think a duplicate is wrong just edit your question and explain why you think it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Jacob Where did you get that concept from? Rude people won't survive very long here, but get banned quickly.

Comment: @Rizier123 I completely agree it is not here to do other peoples jobs, and it is hard to find the balance as some people do it for fun, (like me), Yet on that particular question, I did ask if it was a loading issue or not and if someone could explain where it was, I was right, it was a loading issue, but it was down to my own inexperience in coding with javascript, I found the response from that user was unacceptable really, However i will take your points on board and in the need of a question again, I shall elaborate explicitly :)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, People are rude in many different ways, I thought marking my question as a duplicate which provided an answer that didn't work for me at the time, and refusal to acknowledge that when i tried to explain very rude/immature, And just look at the comments after, I am ashamed of myself, So yes there are alot of rude people, but then there are some very pleasant people that will take 5 minutes to answer your question, rather than going for the quick rep build of closing your question then editing it, If it needed editing they wouldn't have closed them so quick, due to not understanding

Comment: @Ricky For me the duplicate seems reasonable. It basically answered your question and what was left is a simple typo. Now I think to that dupe a simple comment about the typo would have been nice. Also you edited the question and explained that you did changed the code according to the duplicate, but it didn't solved the problem even though I think you could have written that more clearly in your edit.

Comment: After that it went in the reopen queue: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/13999521 and there 3 people decided that it still should stay close. Also I think you could have done a better job at creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you struggle with that you just delete one line by the other and see what lines are required to show and reproduce the error. All in all I think both(you and the other user) were a bit harsh, but also correct in some points. A comment about the typo would have really helped in this situation. The meta question here was a good one :)

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ That has certainly given me abit more insight into "possible duplications" and closed questions from "duplications thank you.

Comment: @Rizier123 I completely agree with the MCVE, I just didn't know where the problem was in the code and was far too tired to narrow it down for the MCVE, That i was completly guilty for and would have accepted any marks for that, (we all have a bad day) I just find it hard to understand the "duplicate" with it, I mean i understand it resolved the problem i was experiencing, yet, in my eyes, the problem lied with the typo first, once that was corrected the "duplicate" answered my problem, Therefore, in my eyes, for the sake of other new users, it should have been closed due to being off-topic.

Comment: That way, it would have been closed and everyone would see that it was a simple typo, stopping the other answers from resolving, This would be a much better help to other "new" users, in the sense of getting them to recheck their code better first, Like i should have.

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic, and will most likely be deleted. Duplicates are considered signposts, and are much less likely to be deleted. There can be good sign posts, which aid in directing googlers, and bad  sign posts, which isnt any easier to find than the rest of the duplicates. Too much duplication is a bad thing. If you were to edit the typo part of your question and the answer, edit the code down to an mcve, and edit the title to reflect the remaining problem in a way that will be aid googlers, then it might be worth keeping around.

Comment: "However in which way is SO going now, Is it still Q/A or turning into a library?" It is, and always was, *both* Q&A and library, which requires certain compromises between these two purposes. The handling of duplicates is a good example of that.

Comment: @Jacob I'm sorry for being rude, that is not my intent. Feel free to make me aware when I am rude, I'll do my best to be nice.

Comment: @Rizier123: can you put all of your comments into an answer?

Comment: Funny thing: I'd say that debugging *is* one of the objectives of SO, at least debugging questions *are* on topic. But it's up to the asker to show that they tried to debug themselves (I'm mostly talking about an MCVE) and not look like a vampire. I'm not saying that this didn't happen in this case (I didn't check), there are many grumpy ones who also grump on properly posed questions.

Comment: @RadLexus I don't think my comments fully answer OP's question that is why I post them as comments.

Comment: @Ricky If you see bad questions, go to SOCVR chat room and tell them. You can also ask them if your answers / questions are good and postable

Comment: @Learn How To Be Transparent: "SOCVR chat room?" Is it "*[SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)*"?

Comment: Yes!!! @PeterMortensen

Comment: @Jacob You seem to imply that the rude people are the ones who close and downvote questions. No, the rude people are the ones who post bad questions because they were to lazy to read the help or post a mcve. People who close these bad questions can be harsh, but usually not rude.

Comment: Related as far as the issue of closing as duplicate when another reason might also apply: [Troubleshooting question wrongly closed as duplicate of how to debug reference](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307332)

Answer (score 22):

> I usually do my best not to be a vampire, and just leech code, so I go through questions on SO and answer if I can when I can.

You don't have to and I strongly discourage you from doing so.

On the one part, people who ask, are no less important than people who answer. They, literally, make this site go. Without questions there will be no answers. So, you already contribute well enough (given you google prior asking and your questions are following the guidelines). You are welcome to ask for help, just don't be a vampire.

On the other part, given you are a learner, most likely your answers will be rather of a cargo cult nature - you've seen some problem, you know a *recipe* and you share it. This is actually the worst kind of answer, because this recipe most likely is outdated and incomplete.

So better leave answers for someone who can give a complete industry standard solution.

> and been negative rep'd etc.

This *is* how this site works. You have to understand that this voting thing is not for you *personally* but just for the question. Voting is the very tool to mark the quality of the post. If your question gets downvoted, do not take offense but try to improve.

> I had already checked that particular question and it did not resolve the issue.

You are slightly misinterpreting the purpose of Stack Overflow here. **By no means this great site is intended to resolve your problems or make your code work.** You have to realize that

- Stack Overflow is all about questions and answers. Nobody says it's about making your code work. Even armed with a perfectly written answer you still can face a lot of issues - from copy/paste errors to *other possible mistakes in your code*, irrelevant to the question asked.
- After all, **it's your job** to make your code work. And nobody else's.

So, if you don't like the outcome (a voting, a closure, an answer that "doesn't resolve your problem"), first ask yourself - is your question *answerable* at all? Is it on a particular issue or just "My code doesn't work, I have no idea why"?

> why he did not mark it as off-topic

It could be a little tricky.

You see, the site mods are quite suspicious here, thinking everyone is about swindle or abuse. So, one cannot singlehandedly close a question as off topic. But a concerned person always trying to close a bad question as soon as possible, in order to discourage both rep-whores and help vampires. Luckily, almost every silly question is a duplicate, and thus can be closed in one click. Don't take it as offense. After all, the outcome is the same - you still need to put some effort. And sooner you'll stop blaming other people for your own mistakes, the sooner you'll have your code working.

> So yes some people do just want a debugging service,

These questions are off topic.

> some ask questions in a manner in which they ask for help to explain how something works (various levels), and get ridiculed and negative rep'd for it.

This is a sad practice, and a consequence of the fact that most people who participate here have no idea what it this site about.

Most people are taking SO for a forum, where some enthusiasts help other enthusiasts with the code. This is why it is often asked in the comments, "what have you tried yourself?".

While the only criteria for the question's quality is **whether the answer would be useful for other programmers?** And so you can tell the SO is mostly misused: a quick eye for a typographic mistake is always appreciated by the crowd, while a question that is asking for the some common problem's solution is often ill-received.

Actually, the proper reaction should be quite the opposite:

- If the answer helped the OP to find the 1000th typo in their code, then the question was bad and should have been closed, not answered.
- While if the answer is giving a canonical solution to a generic problem, then the question was excellent, no matter if the OP was a "loafer", a "help vampire" who didn't even manage to put two lines of code together.

However, this *modus operandi* will never be achieved, for a number of reasons.

Comment: I have the same problem. Now I know I don't have to answer questions. But I am more lucky than OP because most of my answers are upvoted.

Comment: Fantastic answer. On the passage around "the only criteria for the question's quality is whether the answer would be useful for other programmers", I am beginning to see that issue in terms of a confusion between means and ends. Asking e.g. "what have you tried?" can be a means of neutralising "can you debug this for me?" and similar low signal-to-noise questions. If you turn such things in ends in themselves, though, you get overzealous, imperious demands for MCVEs and laser-like focus hanging over anything that isn't about a single piece of code or doesn't have just one possible answer.

Answer (score 19):

> One question even got marked as a duplicate within 60 seconds of posting

Closing duplicates early is important because

- This way people won't lose time repeating what has already been said.
- If the answer is not already covered by the dupetarget, it's better if the answerer answers in the dupetarget instead of in the duplicate.

> Another user pointed out I had a syntax error [...] Stack Overflow is not a debugging site

Blatant syntax errors are off-topic. In JS you can just open the developer console and see the error. Asking someone to fix your typos for you is just making them lose their time.

> Yet this seems to be more and more frowned upon, especially within the JavaScript community

That's because there is a lot of crap in the JS tag.

> I was asking why he did not mark it as off-topic as I would have realised I had an error in my code and resolved it

That's a fair point. The most appropriate close vote for syntax errors would be "off-topic". However, 5 close votes are needed to close a question as off-topic. So the voter must hope that 4 more people will vote too, and that may not ever happen. The closure queue is out-of-control, and close votes do expire.

But for a dupehammer wielder, closing as a duplicate only requires a single vote. So it's better to find a question with the same syntax error and close as a duplicate.

> So is Stack Overflow still a Q&A site for people? After all, it is about helping other people

Yes, Stack Overflow still a Q&A site.

But no, Stack Overflow is not about helping specific people. We're trying to build a repository of good Q&As that will help other people in the future. Not just the asker.