# Don't lock (meta) posts after a failed migration

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, migration, locked-posts

When a Meta post is posted on main, and then migrated to Meta, it becomes difficult to "moderate" the question.

For example, [this recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371220) was migrated, downvoted, and closed.

[image]

Now, it's impossible to cast a delete-vote on the question, because of the "failed" migration. To get the post deleted, we'd have to wait 10 days for the Roomba to do so automatically, or we'd have to use a custom mod flag explaining the situation. (We all know the moderators don't have enough flags to handle yet)

I propose that the restrictions on a failed migration are loosened up. Allow users to delete-vote or comment on the question.

**Especially** when a migration is failed, is when moderation on that question is necessary, as it's been confirmed to be a poor fit for the site.

Comment: somewhat related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354350/i-also-hate-low-quality-non-researched-clueless-meta-questions-that-get-migr

Comment: The post is now deleted anyway

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Because I flagged it (And possibly this question). That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree, seems over convoluted way of handling it, so I think this is a good feature request, just  a shame we have to wait a minimum of 6-8 weeks

Comment: [A similar FR that I posted on the mother meta that proposes getting rid of migration locking entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286419/fix-the-uselessness-of-migration-rejections-by-eliminating-them).

Comment: I've long thought that rejecting a migration to meta if it is closed is a bad design anyway.  Sure, there are bad meta questions that are migrated to meta, but they are still meta questions and belong here.  There is absolutely no reason to send them back to Stack Overflow.  They are easier to clean up on meta.

Comment: Related (and what I see as a better solution for the problem): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299599/dont-treat-closed-questions-on-meta-as-rejected-migrations-from-main

Comment: @gparyani: No, I'm fine with the concept of "failed migration", just not with it resulting in a lock.

Comment: This is now essentially implemented, as migrations from main to meta [aren't rejected and thus locked anymore when closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398121/questions-migrated-to-meta-should-not-be-rejected-when-closed).

Answer (score 20):

Seems backwards in general that failed migration posts are locked out from deletion. What purpose does that serve?

A failed migration confirms that the question is not a fit for the migration target site. I'd imagine these are deleted in almost all circumstances eventually. Why lock normal users out of expediting the process?

Comment: `A failed migration confirms that the question is not a fit for the migration target site` - for meta questions I don't agree.  More likely they are either bad meta questions or don't belong on any site.  The question should stay where it is most easily cleaned up, which is on meta.  So I don't think the locked post is the issue.  The problem is that rejection shouldn't happen to begin with

Comment: @psubsee2003 That speaks to the issue of people misusing close votes on meta as super downvotes. In theory, everything closed as non dupe on meta is not actually a fit for meta.

Comment: @Magisch a closed meta question still belongs on meta.  It should be treated no differently than a bad question asked here originally.  There's no reason for the question to be bounced back and forth.  And the benefit is that it is easier to clean up here.  Sending it back to main and keeping it unlocked makes it harder to find and delete.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I gather "bad meta questions" was what Magisch was getting at by "not a fit for the migration target site". There's a reason we tell users not to migrate crap. I'm personally sick of users casting knee-jerk migrate votes on anything that looks remotely meta. Not everything needs to be migrated just because it looks like it should have been posted there in the first place - in many cases, it *never should have been posted in the first place*.

Comment: @BoltClock That is a fair point.  But once it is migrated, the damage is done, so sending it back really doesn't have a positive impact to the site.  The 5 people who migrated it will likely never see that it got rejected, so there is no virtually educational value.  Leave it on meta and let it get closed, deleted or roomba'd

Comment: @psubsee2003: It looks like you and Magisch are in agreement in that case, actually. "The migrated question is not a good fit on the target site, therefore let users expedite its deletion from the target site if it bothers them so much" is how I'm interpreting it.

Comment: Migrated questions are [deleted automatically 30 days after being rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287891/165773). Though frankly it looks a bit... ugly when apparently bad questions hang on the site for 30 days and can be only cleaned up via mod flag