# Original post left after meta-migrated post was deleted

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, migration

[A question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53335301) was [migrated to Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376735/howto-get-more-reputation-in-stackoverflow) where it was quickly closed as duplicate; but then the OP deleted the meta question.

Now, the (formerly) migrated question is left on Stack Overflow, albeit closed, and eligible for [roomba](/help/roomba) in 10 days.

I would have expected the SO post to be effectively deleted (either as "page not found" or as a redirect to the meta question).

Comment: The SO question is still there because the migration was rejected, due to OP deleting the MSO question.

Comment: They not only deleted but before that confirmed the duplicate themselves. (see the community vote). I believe that triggered the rejection. Either way, unwanted behavior it is ...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the underlying mechanics. Still, the point here is that this is undesirable and arguably unpleasantly surprising behavior, aka a bug.

Comment: Vaguely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354350/i-also-hate-low-quality-non-researched-clueless-meta-questions-that-get-migr

Comment: I disagree about it being a bug. It's standard behaviour when a migration is rejected.

Comment: @Stijn Then the bug is perhaps that the OP can reject the migration so easily, probably without realizing that they are doing it. The end result is still bad for everyone involved.

Comment: For what it's worth the SO question is now also deleted.

Comment: See my update. This circumstance should no longer occur due to system changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a question migrated to a different site is later deleted or closed with any reason other than duplicate, it gets marked rejected. What happened here is that the duplicate closure did nothing, but the OP's deletion rejected the migration. This removed the redirect and effectively reversed all effects of the migration, including the redirect and the lock, except that the original question was left closed as off-topic.

If the rejection occurred more than 30 days after the migration, the migration stub would have been deleted, and then the subsequent OP deletion would have deleted the question on both sites, since migration stubs aren't automatically undeleted if the migration is later rejected.

See the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

---

**Update:** The circumstances in this question should no longer occur, because the system has been changed to no longer mark a migration as "rejected" upon deletion if the question is closed as a duplicate before being deleted.

Comment: Are you trying to explain this is by design?

Comment: @rene Yes, I am.

Comment: too bad the duplicate closure doesn't get precedence over deletion. I hate to write an FR for that though.

Comment: @rene Perhaps the best solution would be to prevent author deletions from marking migrations "rejected".

Comment: Could be. Maybe the rationale is that the OP should be able to find their question at the the original site in case they *disagree* with the migration? Deletion is then their option to contest migration. But I doubt if so much thought went into this feature. Anyway ...